# Replace word with match in CSV

Tags: c#, regex, csv

```
public void replaceText(string messageText)
    {
        int counter = 1;
        string csvFile = "textwords.csv";
        string[] words = messageText.Split(' ');
        char csvSeparator = ',';

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(csvFile))
            {
                foreach (string value in line.Replace("\"", "").Split('\r', '\n',     csvSeparator))
                    if (value.Trim() == word.Trim()) // case sensitive     
                    {
                        messageText = Regex.Replace(messageText, value, string.Empty);

                        messageText = messageText.Insert(counter, " " + line);

                    }
            }
            counter++;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(messageText);
     }
```

So I have the above code, it searches my CSV file for a match to every word in the messageText. The CSV file contains textspeak abbreviations and every time it finds a match it is to replace the word in messageText with the word it found. For example "hi LOL" would find "LOL, Laugh out loud" in the CSV and replace it

However this only works for one replacement. If I put in "Hi LOL" it would output "Hi LOL, Laugh out Loud"

But If I put "Hi LOL, how are you? LMAO" it outputs "Hi LOL LMFAO, Laughing my A** off, how are you?"

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong, I can't figure out why it is doing this

Comment: I can't get my head around what this is supposed to be doing, but to my mind it's somewhat bizarre to read the whole dictionary from file for each word in the message, and you shouldn't be using Regex.Replace to do a simple text replace, and if you're using a replace function, you shouldn't also need to do an 'insert' separately.

Comment: You should probably edit your question to show clearly an input message, the contents of the .CSV file, and what's wrong with the output.

Comment: You were right, been working on this for a while so I'm tired

changed it to just 

messageText = Regex.Replace(messageText, word, line);

Comment: Don't use Regex.Replace like that unless 'word' is a 'regular expression pattern'.   If you're just trying to replace 'word' with 'line' in messageText, use messageText.Replace(word, line)

Answer (score 0):

there are some issues with this method:
1 it takes 2 responsibilities (load key/value pair from csv file and replace text). everytime it's called, the csv file will be loaded.
2 the variable 'counter' looks weird for the purpose of the method.

here is the rewritten code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
        var dictionary = LoadFromFile("c:\textWords.csv");
        var message = "Hi LOL, LMAO";
        message = ReplaceMessage(message, dictionary);
        //
    }

    static Dictionary<String, String> LoadFromFile(String csvFile) {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(csvFile);
        foreach (var line in lines) {
            var fields = line.Split(',', '\r', '\n');
            dictionary[fields[0].Trim()] = fields[1].Trim();
        }
        return dictionary;
    }

    static String ReplaceMessage(String message, Dictionary<String, String> dictionary) {
        var words = message.Split(' ', ',');
        var s = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var word in words) {
            if (dictionary[word] != null) {
                s.Append(String.Format("{0}, {1} ", word, dictionary[word]));
            } else {
                s.Append(word + " ");
            }
        }
        return s.ToString().TrimEnd(' ');
    }
```